# Aws lambda function failing - Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, boto3

This is a very weird problem that I have got stuck into, will really appreciate if someone could provide some direction. I am trying to access value for request_url from web_token.py module.

when I only try to run web_token.py separately over pycharm and print request_url it works fine and generates the url. I zip both these files and upload it to lambda function but when testing it I get an error "Unable to import module 'retrieve_accounts': No module named boto.sts". I even tried putting the code of web_token.py inside retrieve_accounts.py but getting the same error. I am sure I am missing something very basic it looks boto.sts is not being recognized while running the python script. Can somebody please give some guidance. Thank You!

retrieve_accounts.py

```
import boto3
import web_token

def get_account(event, context):

client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
NameID = "testname@org.com"
ManagerEmail = "test1@eorg.com"
response = client.scan(
    TableName='Sandbox-Users',
    ScanFilter={
        'NameID': {
            'AttributeValueList': [
                {
                    'S': NameID,
                },
            ],
            'ComparisonOperator': 'EQ'
        }
    }
)
if response["Count"] > 0:
    client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
    response = client.get_item(
        Key={
            'NameID': {
                'S': NameID,
            },
            'ManagerEmail': {
                'S': ManagerEmail,
            },
        },
        TableName='Sandbox-Users',
    )
    return web_token.request_url ----------->here

else:
    response = client.put_item(
        Item={
            'NameID': {
                'S': NameID,
            },
            'ManagerEmail': {
                'S': ManagerEmail,
            }
        },
        TableName='Sandbox-Users'
    )
    return "Create Account"
```

web_token.py

```
import httplib
import urllib, json
from boto.sts import STSConnection -------->Error here

sts_connection = STSConnection()
assumed_role_object = sts_connection.assume_role(
role_arn="arn:aws:iam::454084028794:role/AMPSandboxRole",
role_session_name="AssumeRoleSession"
)

# Step 3: Format resulting temporary credentials into JSON

json_string_with_temp_credentials = '{'
json_string_with_temp_credentials += '"sessionId":"' + 
assumed_role_object.credentials.access_key + '",'
json_string_with_temp_credentials += '"sessionKey":"' + 
assumed_role_object.credentials.secret_key + '",'
json_string_with_temp_credentials += '"sessionToken":"' + 
assumed_role_object.credentials.session_token + '"'
json_string_with_temp_credentials += '}'

# Step 4. Make request to AWS federation endpoint to get sign-in token. 
Construct the parameter string with the sign-in action request, a 12-hour session duration, and the JSON 
   document with temporary credentials as parameters.

request_parameters = "?Action=getSigninToken"
   request_parameters += "&SessionDuration=43200"
   request_parameters += "&Session=" + 
   urllib.quote_plus(json_string_with_temp_credentials)
   request_url = "/federation" + request_parameters
   conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("signin.aws.amazon.com")
   conn.request("GET", request_url)
   r = conn.getresponse()
   # Returns a JSON document with a single element named SigninToken.
   signin_token = json.loads(r.read())
   request_parameters = "?Action=login"
   request_parameters += "&Issuer=sandbox.com"
   request_parameters += "&Destination=" + 
   urllib.quote_plus("https://console.aws.amazon.com/")
   request_parameters += "&SigninToken=" + signin_token["SigninToken"]
   request_url = "https://signin.aws.amazon.com/federation" + 
   request_parameters
```

Comment: Why are you mixing boto and boto3 there? Stick with boto3 with something like `import boto3; client = boto3.client('sts')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Lambda Python environments include boto3 (and botocore). They don't include the older boto (a precursor to boto3), hence the import failure.

You could potentially include boto in your upload but it's not advisable to mix boto and boto3 if you can avoid it. Use one or the other, preferably boto3.

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance I appreciate it.